# Maven : include JAR's classes into another JAR

Tags: maven

I want to generate JAR file with some classes of another JAR (but not all classes). I know I can use `maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies` to include JAR into another JAR but how can I include only some classes and not the entire JAR please ?

Comment: too hard for me ^^ I'm looking for an existing solution

Comment: You can include/exclude in the configuration of the maven-dependency-plugin. See [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

Comment: Hmm many thanks, it's look like what I want

Comment: I will form it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include/exclude in the configuration of the maven-dependency-plugin.

See [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which allows including dependencies, but also allows transforming their package names (along will all references to them) so that the resulting überjar is safe from classpath duplicates if the bundled JAR is also on the classpath.

One example is [this pom.xml](https://github.com/cloudbees/cloudbees-api-client/blob/master/cloudbees-api-client-nodeps/pom.xml) where for example the XStream classes used are relocated to a different package. This allows the jar file to be used in an application that uses a different and incompatible version of XStream (in this case the artifact is used in a Jenkins plugin)